# Executar a função uma vez pegar o return e usar em um laço codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, return

Olá

Estou com problemas para recuperar o return de um model e usar em um laço(foreach), sem que a função seja executada novamente varias vezes...

Como posso fazer para pegar o return e usar este mesmo return varias vezes?

Código para ilustração:

```
    $valorModel = $this->model->funcao(); // recupera o return


    foreach ($var as $var2) {
        $array = array(
            'colunaDb' => $var2->item,
            'colunaDb' => $valorModel, // executa a função varias vezes
            'colunaDb' => $var2->item
        );
            }
```

Comment: Seria bom postar parte do código para ajudar na compreensão...

Comment: postei um código para ilustrar o meu problema

Comment: Você retornou o $query->result()? Se retornar apenas um elemento , por exemplo use no retorno da funcão a $query->rows->nome_do_campo.

Answer (score 0):

Uma idéia, faça o seguinte, dentro do seu model declare um private $var... uma estrutura similar a esta:

```
class Model {
    public $email;

    public function findEmailById($id){
        // ... função que busca no banco de dados, etc...
        $this->email = $retorno; // $retorno seria a variável com o resultado da sua query ou função. ao invés de usar um return $var.
    }

    public function getEmail(){
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

Agora no seu controlador, use o seu código assim:

```
$this->load->model('model');
$m = new Model();
$m->funcao();  // recupera o return

    foreach ($var as $var2) {
        $array = array(
            'colunaDb' => $var2->item,
            'colunaDb' => $m->getEmail(), // pega apenas o email já salvo pela função
            'colunaDb' => $var2->item
        );
```

Pronto, simples e sem repetir N vezes a função... Abraço...